# How to get cell position based on multiple criteria in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have to find a worksheet cell position based on matching some other cell values.

[image]

Suppose, SKU is 0.14X900 and Item_ID is 2 and Machine is Machine2, then it will right Quantity in cell D3

```
Dim SKU_value As String
Dim Item_Id_Value As long
Dim Machine As String
Dim Quantity As long


Dim row_num As Long
row_num = Worksheets("myWorkSheet").Range("A1:E7").Find(What:=SKU_Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

I can read row number by matching with one variable(SKU_Value) only, is there any way to find the exact cell value for multiple matching options here?

Comment: Where is it picking the quantity from? Also If I have understood you correctly, this can be achieved using Excel formulas. No need for VBA.

Comment: all 4 variables will get data from other portion of code and instead of formula I have to write this in VBA :)

Comment: You can use `Evaluate` to use formula in VBA as well.Alternatively you can use [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/). Find SKU first and then use `.Offest` to match other values.

Comment: Are the`Item_id` values unique as shown in your example, or can you have more than 1 item with the same `Item_Id` ?

Comment: Can there be a case like Sku is 0.17X914 and Item Id is 2? If possible which row would you consider?

Answer (score 0):

You could try "AutoFilter":

```
    With ActiveSheet.Range("a1:e5")
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=SKU_Value, Operator:=xlAnd
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Item_ID_Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Resize(, 1).Offset(, 3).Value = Quantity
        .AutoFilter
    End With
```

The two autofilter methods result in showing row 1 (the header row) and any row that matches your SKU and Item ID. Since the resulting range is not contiguous, it comprises two areas; the first is the header row and the second is your data row (If the first row of data is a match, .Areas(2) will bomb, though, so you'll have to do some testing and use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Resize(1, 1).Offset(1, 3).Value = Quantity`

Comment: You could also iterate the visible cells if there is more than one matching row, and I used hard-coded numbers instead of matching (for example, "Machine 2" is offset from the SKU column by 3, so `.Offset(, 3)` could be changed based upon a matching function).